# Can't install XNA

Tags: visual-studio-2005, xna

I'm trying to install XNA.
When the installation starts I got an error that says "XNA GSE 1.0 refresh requires Visual C# 2005 express edition sp1..."

I use Windows 7 and I have Visual Studio 2008 & Visual C 2008 Express.

When I saw this message I installed Visual C 2005 Express and then I got the same error again. So I installed Visual C 2005 sp1.

I restarted after installation and I still got this error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading the newest version of XNA, and you'll probably get better results:

[Useful XNA Downloads](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/downloads)

[XNA Game Studio 3.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=80782277-d584-42d2-8024-893fcd9d3e82&displaylang=en)

[Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try installing XNA 3.0 instead of that super-old version. It supports Visual Studio 2008 (and a million other features that XNA 1.0 doesn't support).